# Power-user fast countdown reminder for reminding of awaited task while multitasking

Tags: windows, reminders

## Sounds confusing? Let me explain.

Many PC related jobs require a user to do multiple things at once. As an example, I will bring out a developer's job:

- you build an app - you have to wait
- you run a long running local test - you have to wait
- you commit a code and want to submit it to a code review, but there is a latency before it is available - you have to wait
- you want to remind reviewers to review the code when a reasonable time passes - but you need to be reminded yourself to remind them, who is supposed to remember all of this?
- you run a long running query, not sure when it finishes - gazing won't make it go faster - you have to wait again.

All of these require you to remember, where you were in a pipeline of getting a task done and in a point in time remember, that you should check if you can move further.

For this purpose I wanted to have a super simple, extremely fast keyboard shortcut friendly tool to use, that would just remind me to check if I can move further in the pipelines.

### At the moment I am using more or less good tool for this called [Free Countdown Timer](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Countdown-Timer/3000-2350_4-75330413.html).

[image: screenshot of free countdown timer]

I used some tiny autohotkey scripts to make the usage faster - invokes the window and opens a "new reminder" dialog.

However, I presume there are nicer, more evolved tools for this job and I would like you to suggest your favourite.

### Remember the use case:

- as least necessary steps (keystrokes) for a new reminder as possible.
- I must be able to create a new reminder quickly WITHOUT the usage of mouse.
- if I can click on a link which is the text in the reminder to open it, that is more useful, then having to copy it.
- customizable snoozing behaviour and play sound length is a plus.

Some of it the software I proposed offers, but it would need some polishing to be really good.

### Some bad examples of what I am NOT looking for:

- heavy weight thing like Outlook where you have tasks and functionality, but creating a reminder would take forever compared to this. Remember, I need something to remind me to check if a test or a query is finished in 5 minutes(!) while I go work on something else.
- ToDo software - I am not looking for a list of things that I need to do, when I have the time - I have tools for that and they are rather complex and not all To dos you need to be reminded about in a specific time - so no to do apps.ň
- Android apps - We are talking about a PC workflow - an Android app can be quick and beautiful - but you have to unlock your phone, use the app and you cannot type on the PC keyboard and move fluently.

So, basically, I start a task X, and want to set a reminder that in e.g. 10 minutes tells me to check if X is done. Such a tiny thing should be either free, or rather cheap, since it has little responsibility. (so under 8 € or 10 $ I guess).